# set switch button state according to share preference value android

Tags: android

I have a custom switch button which i am using for attendance purpose.I am saving the value in shared prefernces.the values are being retrieved very well but the state of the switch button needs to be changed on create according to value of shared preferences.For example if the value is true then button will be in unchecked state and if false button will be in checked state.how to achieve this?

```
 getPreference();

    if(Common.punchedIn) {
       // switchButton.setOnCheckedChangeListener(null);
        switchButton.setChecked(false);
    }
    else
    {
       // switchButton.setOnCheckedChangeListener(null);
        switchButton.setChecked(true);
    }



switchButton.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new MySwitchButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
@Override
public void onCheckedChanged(MySwitchButton s, boolean isChecked) {
    if(switchButton.isChecked()){
        String acTime = getActionTime();
        String acDate = getActionDate();
        String loc = getGPSLocation();
        String empID = getEmployeeID();
        String empReportingTo = getReportingTo();
        //Toast.makeText(AttendanceActivity.this, "Switch is currently ON", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        punchStatus_text.setText("Punch Out");
        shift_dur_text.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        shift_dur_time.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        checkin_time.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        checkin_time.setText("Check in :"+acTime);
        checkout_time.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        saveAttendance(empID,empReportingTo,acDate,acTime,loc,"na","na","IN");
    }else{
        String acTime = getActionTime();
        String acDate = getActionDate();
        String loc = getGPSLocation();
        String empID = getEmployeeID();
        String empReportingTo = getReportingTo();
        //Toast.makeText(AttendanceActivity.this, "Switch is currently OFF", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        punchStatus_text.setText("Punch In");
        shift_dur_text.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        shift_dur_time.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        checkin_time.setText("Check in :"+Common.punchInTime);
        checkin_time.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        checkout_time.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        checkout_time.setText("Check Out:"+acTime);
        saveAttendance(empID,empReportingTo,acDate,acTime,loc,"na","na","OUT");
    }
}

});
```

saving and retrieving from share preference

```
public static boolean setPreference(Context context,boolean value) {
    SharedPreferences settings = context.getSharedPreferences("sharedPref", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
        editor.putBoolean("punch",value);


    return editor.commit();
}

public void getPreference() {
    SharedPreferences settings = this.getSharedPreferences("sharedPref", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    //  Toast.makeText(this,"EMP ID is "+emp_id,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    Common.punchedIn = settings.getBoolean("punch", false);
    Toast.makeText(this,"PUNCH IN STATUS "+String.valueOf(Common.punchedIn),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

SWITCH BUTTON CLASS

```
public class MySwitchButton extends View implements Checkable {
private static final int ANIMATION_DURATION = 300;

private static final int DEFAULT_WIDTH = 100;
private static final int DEFAULT_HEIGHT = 50;
private static final int DEFAULT_SPOT_PADDING = 6;
private static final int DEFAULT_BORDER_WIDTH = 4;

private static final int DEFAULT_SWITCH_ON_COLOR = Color.LTGRAY;
private static final int DEFAULT_SWITCH_ON_COLOR_OUT = Color.LTGRAY;
private static final int DEFAULT_SWITCH_OFF_COLOR = Color.LTGRAY;
private static final int DEFAULT_SWITCH_OFF_COLOR_OUT = Color.LTGRAY;
private static final int DEFAULT_SPOT_ON_COLOR = R.color.colorBrown;
private static final int DEFAULT_SPOT_ON_COLOR_IN = R.color.colorBrown;
private static final int DEFAULT_SPOT_OFF_COLOR = R.color.colorBrown;
private static final int DEFAULT_SPOT_OFF_COLOR_IN = R.color.colorBrown;

private static final int SWITCH_OFF_POS = 0;
private static final int SWITCH_ON_POS = 1;

private int switchOnColor;
private int switchOffColor;
private int spotOnColor;
private int spotOnColorIn;
private int spotOffColor;
private int spotOffColorIn;
private int switchOnStrokeColor;
private int switchOffStrokeColor;
private int spotPadding;
private float currentPos;
private boolean mChecked;
private boolean mBroadcasting;
private boolean isMoving;
private int duration;

private OnCheckedChangeListener onCheckedChangeListener;

private ValueAnimator valueAnimator;

private enum State {
    SWITCH_ANIMATION_OFF, SWITCH_ANIMATION_ON, SWITCH_ON, SWITCH_OFF
}

private State state;

public MySwitchButton(Context context) {
    super(context);
    switchOnColor = DEFAULT_SWITCH_ON_COLOR;
    switchOffColor = DEFAULT_SWITCH_OFF_COLOR;
    spotOnColor = DEFAULT_SPOT_ON_COLOR;
    spotOnColorIn = DEFAULT_SPOT_ON_COLOR_IN;
    spotOffColor = DEFAULT_SPOT_OFF_COLOR;
    spotOffColorIn = DEFAULT_SPOT_OFF_COLOR_IN;
    spotPadding = dp2px(DEFAULT_SPOT_PADDING);
    switchOnStrokeColor = switchOnColor;
    switchOffStrokeColor = switchOffColor;
    duration = ANIMATION_DURATION;
    state = mChecked ? State.SWITCH_ON : State.SWITCH_OFF;

    setClickable(true);
}

public MySwitchButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.Switch);
    switchOnColor = a.getColor(R.styleable.Switch_switchOnColor, DEFAULT_SWITCH_ON_COLOR);
    switchOffColor = a.getColor(R.styleable.Switch_switchOffColor, DEFAULT_SWITCH_OFF_COLOR);
   // switchOnColor = getResources().getColor(R.color.colorBrown);
    //switchOffColor = getResources().getColor(R.color.colorBrown);
    spotOnColor = a.getColor(R.styleable.Switch_spotOnColor, DEFAULT_SPOT_ON_COLOR);
    spotOnColorIn = a.getColor(R.styleable.Switch_spotOnColor, DEFAULT_SPOT_ON_COLOR_IN);
    spotOffColor = a.getColor(R.styleable.Switch_spotOffColor, DEFAULT_SPOT_OFF_COLOR);
    spotOffColorIn = a.getColor(R.styleable.Switch_spotOnColor, DEFAULT_SPOT_OFF_COLOR_IN);
    spotPadding = a.getDimensionPixelSize(R.styleable.Switch_spotPadding, dp2px(DEFAULT_SPOT_PADDING));
    switchOnStrokeColor = a.getColor(R.styleable.Switch_switchOnStrokeColor, switchOnColor);
    switchOffStrokeColor = a.getColor(R.styleable.Switch_switchOffStrokeColor, switchOffColor);
    duration = a.getInteger(R.styleable.Switch_duration, ANIMATION_DURATION);
    mChecked = a.getBoolean(R.styleable.Switch_checked, false);
    a.recycle();

    state = mChecked ? State.SWITCH_ON : State.SWITCH_OFF;
    setClickable(true);
}

@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    int widthSpecSize = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
    int heightSpecSize = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);
    int widthSpecMode = MeasureSpec.getMode(widthMeasureSpec);
    int heightSpecMode = MeasureSpec.getMode(heightMeasureSpec);

    int width = dp2px(DEFAULT_WIDTH) + getPaddingLeft() + getPaddingRight();
    int height = dp2px(DEFAULT_HEIGHT) + getPaddingTop() + getPaddingBottom();

    if (widthSpecMode != MeasureSpec.AT_MOST) {
        width = Math.max(width, widthSpecSize);
    }

    if (heightSpecMode != MeasureSpec.AT_MOST) {
        height = Math.max(height, heightSpecSize);
    }

    setMeasuredDimension(width, height);

}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    int w = getWidth();
    int h = getHeight();
    int pl = getPaddingLeft();
    int pt = getPaddingTop();
    int pr = getPaddingRight();
    int pb = getPaddingBottom();
    int wp = w - pl - pr;
    int hp = h - pt - pb;
    int sw = dp2px(DEFAULT_WIDTH);
    int sh = dp2px(DEFAULT_HEIGHT);

    int dx = pl + (wp - sw) / 2;
    int dy = pt + (hp - sh) / 2;
    canvas.translate(dx, dy);

    switch (state) {
        case SWITCH_ON:
            drawSwitchOn(canvas);
            break;
        case SWITCH_OFF:
            drawSwitchOff(canvas);
            break;
        case SWITCH_ANIMATION_ON:
            drawSwitchOnAnim(canvas);
            break;
        case SWITCH_ANIMATION_OFF:
            drawSwitchOffAnim(canvas);
            break;
    }
}

private void drawSwitchOn(Canvas canvas) {
    float[] rectAttrs = compRoundRectAttr(SWITCH_OFF_POS);
    drawRoundRect(canvas, switchOnColor, rectAttrs);

    float[] ovalAttrs = compOvalAttr(SWITCH_ON_POS);
    drawOval(canvas, spotOnColor, ovalAttrs);
    drawOvalIn(canvas, spotOnColorIn, ovalAttrs);

    drawRoundRectStroke(canvas, DEFAULT_SWITCH_ON_COLOR_OUT);
}

private void drawSwitchOff(Canvas canvas) {
    float[] rectAttrs = compRoundRectAttr(SWITCH_OFF_POS);
    drawRoundRect(canvas, switchOffColor, rectAttrs);

    float[] ovalAttrs = compOvalAttr(SWITCH_OFF_POS);
    drawOval(canvas, spotOffColor,  ovalAttrs);
    drawOvalIn(canvas, spotOffColorIn, ovalAttrs);

    drawRoundRectStroke(canvas, DEFAULT_SWITCH_OFF_COLOR_OUT);
}

private void drawSwitchOnAnim(Canvas canvas) {
    float[] rectAttrs = compRoundRectAttr(SWITCH_OFF_POS);
    drawRoundRect(canvas, switchOnColor, rectAttrs);

    rectAttrs = compRoundRectAttr(currentPos);
    drawRoundRect(canvas, switchOffColor, rectAttrs);

    float[] ovalShadeOnAttrs = compRoundRectShadeOnAttr(currentPos * 3/2);
    float[] ovalAttrs = compOvalAttr(currentPos* 3/2);
    int color = compColor(currentPos, DEFAULT_SPOT_OFF_COLOR, DEFAULT_SPOT_ON_COLOR);
    int colorIn = compColor(currentPos, DEFAULT_SPOT_OFF_COLOR_IN, DEFAULT_SPOT_ON_COLOR_IN);
    drawRoundRect(canvas, color, ovalShadeOnAttrs);
    drawOval(canvas, color, ovalAttrs);
    drawOvalIn(canvas, colorIn, ovalAttrs);

    int strokeColor = compColor(currentPos, DEFAULT_SWITCH_OFF_COLOR_OUT, DEFAULT_SWITCH_ON_COLOR_OUT);
    drawRoundRectStroke(canvas, strokeColor);
}

private void drawSwitchOffAnim(Canvas canvas) {
    float[] rectAttrs = compRoundRectAttr(SWITCH_OFF_POS);
    if (currentPos != 1) {
        drawRoundRect(canvas, switchOffColor, rectAttrs);
    }

    rectAttrs = compRoundRectAttr(1 - currentPos);
    drawRoundRect(canvas, switchOffColor, rectAttrs);

    float[] ovalAttrs;
    if(currentPos > 2.0/3){
        ovalAttrs = compOvalAttr(0);
    }else{
        ovalAttrs = compOvalAttr(1 - currentPos * 3/2);
    }
    float[] ovalShadeOffAttrs = compRoundRectShadeOffAttr(1 - currentPos * 3/2);
    int color = compColor(currentPos, DEFAULT_SPOT_ON_COLOR, DEFAULT_SPOT_OFF_COLOR);
    int colorIn = compColor(currentPos, DEFAULT_SPOT_ON_COLOR_IN, DEFAULT_SPOT_OFF_COLOR_IN);
    drawRoundRect(canvas, color, ovalShadeOffAttrs);
    drawOval(canvas, color, ovalAttrs);
    drawOvalIn(canvas, colorIn, ovalAttrs);

    int strokeColor = compColor(currentPos, DEFAULT_SWITCH_ON_COLOR_OUT, DEFAULT_SWITCH_OFF_COLOR_OUT);
    drawRoundRectStroke(canvas, strokeColor);
}

private void drawRoundRect(Canvas canvas, int color, float[] attrs) {
    Paint paint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
    paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
    paint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
    RectF rectF = new RectF();
    paint.setColor(color);
    rectF.set(attrs[0], attrs[1], attrs[2], attrs[3]);
    canvas.drawRoundRect(rectF, attrs[4], attrs[4], paint);
}

private void drawRoundRectStroke(Canvas canvas, int color) {
    int sw = dp2px(DEFAULT_WIDTH);
    int sh = dp2px(DEFAULT_HEIGHT);

    float left = dp2pxFloat((float) 2.4);
    float right = sw - left;
    float top = dp2pxFloat((float) 2.4);
    float bottom = sh - top;
    float radius = (bottom - top) * 0.5f;

    Paint paint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
    paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    paint.setColor(color);
    paint.setStrokeWidth(dp2pxFloat((float) 3.6));
    RectF rectF = new RectF();
    rectF.set(left, top, right, bottom);
    canvas.drawRoundRect(rectF, radius, radius, paint);
}

private void drawOvalIn(Canvas canvas, int color, float[] attrs) {
    Paint paint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
    paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
    paint.setColor(color);
    int borderWidth = dp2px(DEFAULT_BORDER_WIDTH);
    RectF rectFIn = new RectF(attrs[0] + borderWidth, attrs[1] + borderWidth, attrs[2] - borderWidth, attrs[3] - borderWidth);
    canvas.drawOval(rectFIn, paint);
}

private void drawOval(Canvas canvas, int color, float[] attrs) {
    Paint paint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
    paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
    paint.setColor(color);
    RectF rectF = new RectF(attrs[0], attrs[1], attrs[2], attrs[3]);
    canvas.drawOval(rectF, paint);
}

private float[] compRoundRectAttr(float pos) {
    int sw = dp2px(DEFAULT_WIDTH);
    int sh = dp2px(DEFAULT_HEIGHT);

    float left = sw * pos;
    float right = sw - left;
    float top = sh * pos;
    float bottom = sh - top;
    float radius = (bottom - top) * 0.5f;

    return new float[]{left, top, right, bottom, radius};
}

private float[] compRoundRectShadeOnAttr(float pos) {
    int sw = dp2px(DEFAULT_WIDTH);
    int sh = dp2px(DEFAULT_HEIGHT);
    int oh = sh - 2 * spotPadding;
    float left, right, top, bottom;
    if(pos < 0.35){
        left = 0;
        right = spotPadding + (sw - sh) * pos + oh;
        top = spotPadding;
        bottom = oh + top;
    }else{
        left = spotPadding + (sw - sh) * pos *2/3;
        right = spotPadding + (sw - sh) * pos *2/3+ oh;
        top = spotPadding;
        bottom = oh + top;
    }
    float radius = (bottom - top) * 0.5f;
    return new float[]{left, top, right, bottom, radius};
}

private float[] compRoundRectShadeOffAttr(float pos) {
    int sw = dp2px(DEFAULT_WIDTH);
    int sh = dp2px(DEFAULT_HEIGHT);
    int oh = sh - 2 * spotPadding;
    float left, right, top, bottom;

    if(pos > 0.65){
        left = spotPadding + (sw - sh) * pos;
        right = sw - spotPadding;
        top = spotPadding;
        bottom = oh + top;
    }else{
        left = spotPadding + (sw - sh) * (2*pos + 1)/3;
        right = spotPadding + (sw - sh) * (2*pos + 1)/3 + oh;
        top = spotPadding;
        bottom = oh + top;
    }
    float radius = (bottom - top) * 0.5f;
    return new float[]{left, top, right, bottom, radius};
}

private float[] compOvalAttr(float pos) {
    if(pos > 1){
        pos = 1;
    }
    int sw = dp2px(DEFAULT_WIDTH);
    int sh = dp2px(DEFAULT_HEIGHT);
    int oh = sh - 2 * spotPadding;

    float left = spotPadding + (sw - sh) * pos;
    float right = left + oh;
    float top = spotPadding;
    float bottom = oh + top;

    return new float[]{left, top, right, bottom};
}

private int compColor(float fraction, int startColor, int endColor) {
    return (Integer) new ArgbEvaluator().evaluate(fraction, startColor, endColor);
}

@Override
public boolean performClick() {
    toggle();

    final boolean handled = super.performClick();
    if (!handled) {
        // View only makes a sound effect if the onClickListener was
        // called, so we'll need to make one here instead.
        playSoundEffect(SoundEffectConstants.CLICK);
    }

    return handled;
}

public int dp2px(float dpValue) {
    float scale = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
    return (int) (dpValue * scale + 0.5f);
}

public float dp2pxFloat(float dpValue) {
    float scale = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
    return dpValue * scale + 0.5f;
}

@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
@Override
public void setChecked(boolean checked) {
    if (isMoving) {
        return;
    }

    if (mChecked != checked) {
        mChecked = checked;

        // Avoid infinite recursions if setChecked() is called from a listener
        if (mBroadcasting) {
            return;
        }

        mBroadcasting = true;
        if (onCheckedChangeListener != null) {
            onCheckedChangeListener.onCheckedChanged(this, mChecked);
        }
        mBroadcasting = false;

        if (mChecked) {
            state = State.SWITCH_ANIMATION_ON;
        } else {
            state = State.SWITCH_ANIMATION_OFF;
        }

        if (isAttachedToWindow() && isLaidOut()) {
            animateToCheckedState();
        } else {
            // Immediately move the thumb to the new position.
            cancelPositionAnimator();
            currentPos = 0;
        }
    }
}

private void cancelPositionAnimator() {
    if (valueAnimator != null) {
        valueAnimator.cancel();
    }
}

private void animateToCheckedState() {
    valueAnimator = ValueAnimator.ofFloat(0, 1);
    valueAnimator.setDuration(duration);
    valueAnimator.setInterpolator(new AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator());
    valueAnimator.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {
            currentPos = (float) animation.getAnimatedValue();
            invalidate();
        }
    });

    valueAnimator.addListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animator animation) {
            super.onAnimationStart(animation);
            isMoving = true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
            super.onAnimationEnd(animation);
            isMoving = false;
        }
    });

    if (!valueAnimator.isRunning()) {
        valueAnimator.start();
        currentPos = 0;
    }
}

public int getDuration() {
    return duration;
}

public void setDuration(int duration) {
    this.duration = duration;
}

@Override
public boolean isChecked() {
    return mChecked;
}

@Override
public void toggle() {
    setChecked(!mChecked);
}

public int getSwitchOnColor() {
    return switchOnColor;
}

public void setSwitchOnColor(@ColorInt int switchOnColor) {
    this.switchOnColor = switchOnColor;
    invalidate();
}

public int getSwitchOffColor() {
    return switchOffColor;
}

public void setSwitchOffColor(@ColorInt int switchOffColor) {
    this.switchOffColor = switchOffColor;
    invalidate();
}

public int getSpotOnColor() {
    return spotOnColor;
}

public void setSpotOnColor(@ColorInt int spotOnColor) {
    this.spotOnColor = spotOnColor;
    invalidate();
}

public int getSpotOffColor() {
    return spotOffColor;
}

public void setSpotOffColor(@ColorInt int spotOffColor) {
    this.spotOffColor = spotOffColor;
    invalidate();
}

public int getSpotPadding() {
    return spotPadding;
}

public void setSpotPadding(int spotPadding) {
    this.spotPadding = spotPadding;
    invalidate();
}

public int getSwitchOffStrokeColor() {
    return switchOffStrokeColor;
}

public void setSwitchOffStrokeColor(int switchOffStrokeColor) {
    this.switchOffStrokeColor = switchOffStrokeColor;
    invalidate();
}

public int getSwitchOnStrokeColor() {
    return switchOnStrokeColor;
}

public void setSwitchOnStrokeColor(int switchOnStrokeColor) {
    this.switchOnStrokeColor = switchOnStrokeColor;
    invalidate();
}

public OnCheckedChangeListener getOnCheckedChangeListener() {
    return onCheckedChangeListener;
}

public void setOnCheckedChangeListener(OnCheckedChangeListener onCheckedChangeListener) {
    this.onCheckedChangeListener = onCheckedChangeListener;
}

public interface OnCheckedChangeListener {
    /**
     * Called when the checked state of a switch has changed.
     *
     * @param s         The switch whose state has changed.
     * @param isChecked The new checked state of switch.
     */
    void onCheckedChanged(MySwitchButton s, boolean isChecked);
}
```

}

Comment: setchecked(true)

Comment: i tried but as soon as I close the app and open again it is back to uncheched state

Comment: Did you use commit() or apply() after saving value in SharedPreference?

Comment: do in onResume also

Comment: no issue with share preference.I can see the changed value but I cannot see the changed state in button according to the changed value

Comment: Can you tell from where you are getting value? Is it Common.punchedIn in?

Comment: i have edited my question with the share pref code

Comment: where did you call setpreference() method

Comment: @payalgarg check my answer, invoke setpreference() in onCheckedChanged()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For all those facing similar issues this is how I did it

There are static int variables in MySwitchButton class and I just swapped the position.Its now working fine

```
getPreference();

    if (Common.punchedIn) {
        switchButton.setOnCheckedChangeListener(null);
        //switchButton.setChecked(false);
        punchStatus_text.setText("Punch Out");
        MySwitchButton.SWITCH_OFF_POS=1;
        MySwitchButton.SWITCH_ON_POS=0;
        //setColorPreference(AttendanceActivity.this,Color.GREEN,Color.RED);
    } else {
        switchButton.setOnCheckedChangeListener(null);
        //switchButton.setChecked(true);
        punchStatus_text.setText("Punch In");
        MySwitchButton.SWITCH_OFF_POS=0;
        MySwitchButton.SWITCH_ON_POS=1;
        //setColorPreference(AttendanceActivity.this,Color.RED,Color.GREEN);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using handlers that check value after some interval and accordingly change the state of the switch automatically to checked or unchecked.

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() 
{ public void run() 
{ runOnUiThread(new Runnable() 
{ public void run() {  
    if(check) { 
     aSwitch.setChecked(true);
    }
    else { 
      aSwitch.setChecked(false); 
      }
} }); } }, 5000);
```

Comment: please give an example

Comment: new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    if(check){
                    aSwitch.setChecked(true);
                    }
                    else {
                        aSwitch.setChecked(false);
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }, 5000);

Answer (score 0):

You need to **`set value in preferences`** when the switch state is changed,

```
switchButton.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new MySwitchButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(MySwitchButton s, boolean isChecked) {
         setPreference(context,ischecked);
         //your code
    }

    });
```

EDIT:

In your oncreate() method, use

```
 switchButton.setChecked(getPreference());
```

And directly return value in getPreference() method as,

```
public boolean getPreference() {
    SharedPreferences settings = this.getSharedPreferences("sharedPref", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    //  Toast.makeText(this,"EMP ID is "+emp_id,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    Common.punchedIn = settings.getBoolean("punch", false);
    Toast.makeText(this,"PUNCH IN STATUS "+String.valueOf(Common.punchedIn),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    return Common.punchedIn;
}
```

Comment: i have already done that and I dont have any issue with setting and retrieving values.the issue is with setting the button state onCreate according to the value in share prefrence

Comment: still does not change the button state onCreate

Answer (score 0):

Replace your onCreate code with this, after retrieve the shared-preference data:

```
switchButton.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                if(Common.punchedIn) {
                    switchButton.setChecked(false);
                }
                else {
                    switchButton.setChecked(true);
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: sorry didnt work.I am editing my question with my custom switch button class.please check that as well